# Add Service Reference to Old Service

Tags: wcf, mex

I have a need to hook into an old service that is running via a Windows Service that launches a service host through HTTP at runtime.  I can't seem to find out how to get my 'Add Service Reference" to work.  I know the service is running as the log file shows that.  Here's the config entries for the service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="blah.blah.WCF_Service.EngineServiceBehavior" name="blah.blah.WCF_Service.EngineService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8455/EngineService/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="Engine" bindingName="EngineBinding" contract="blah.blah.IEngineService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="Mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8455/EngineService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="blah.blah.EngineServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

It has a mex endpoint being set, but I can't see how to construct the url to get the service information.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try `http://localhost:8455/EngineService/mex`?

Comment: Turns out the problem I was having was that the server was blocking that port.  I could only hit 80.  Changed the firewall settings and was able to add it.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need some details to add service reference. 
in your project, right-click 'References' and select 'Add service reference ...' and enter the address John Saunders mentioned. and then click 'Go'.
[image]